# IntelliJ XSLT debugger not hitting breakpoints

Tags: debugging, xslt, intellij-idea, breakpoints

I'm trying to use IntelliJ's built in XSLT support to debug an XSLT transformation.  However, I cannot get any breakpoints to get hit.  Yes, I hit the debug icon on the run configuration.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If the run configuration is set to use the 'default console' in the 'Output', the debugger will not hit breakpoints.  When selecting 'Show in extra console tab' the debugger will open and pause at the breakpoints.

Comment: Could you elaborate on how to set the `Show in extra console tab` value?

Comment: In the XSLT run configuration settings.  It's a radio button that needs to be selected.

Comment: Thanks Tombstone, I guess I was looking at the XSLT debugger in Visual Studio, and not in IntelliJ :)